# servlet its receiving JSON post, but not display it

Tags: javascript, java, post, servlets

I am doing this at JAVA

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("TEST TOMCAT SERVLET");
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
        data.append(s);
    }
    data.toString(); //Datos que llegan

  }

}
```

When i initialize the app. I recieve in the Servlet:
"TEST TOMCAT SERVLET"
but i am not recevieng this:

```
 return fetch(PUSH_ENDPOINT, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
  token: token,
  user: 'Brent'
  })
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `toString()` doesn't do what you want.

Do a `System.out.println(data.toString()); //Datos que llegan`.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing to print de data

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the respone to the client. Here is an example how you can do that:

```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
   }
```